# In an ItemControl binding to property doesent work but binding to DataContext does

Tags: silverlight, binding, datacontext, itemscontrol

when I run this code the Item-object in my CustomControl becomes a System.Windows.Data.Binding containing nothing but null values but the DataContext becomes an MyClass object (which Items is populated with)

```
<UserControl x:Name="thisControl">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=thisControl,Path=Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <local:UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:CustomControl Item="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My CustomControl class

```
public partial class CustomControl : UserControl
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object Item { get; set; }
}
```

is there something i don't know about ItemsControl?
this is written in Silverlight 4.0

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for you to be attempting to assign the custom control DataContext.  The ItemsControl will take care of that for you.

Also your `CustomControl` code needs to specify the `Item` property as a `DependencyProperty` for the binding to work.  Binding doesn't work on plain ordinary properties.

Example:

```
    public object Item
    {
        get { return GetValue(ItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Item",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(CustomControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null))
```

(I assume that `RSListBoxStopItem` is a typo and you meant to generalise to `CustomControl`)

Comment: Yes, how could i forgot that. Thank you, it solved my problem.